# How to reload ui chart in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, charts, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angularjs-ui-bootstrap theme.i want to drow pie chart

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading font-bold">Package Plan purchases</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div ui-jq="plot" ui-options="
              {{chartdata}},
              {
                series: { pie: { show: true, innerRadius: 0.5, stroke: { width: 0 }, label: { show: true, threshold: 0.05 } } },
                colors: ['{{app.color.primary}}','{{app.color.info}}','{{app.color.success}}','{{app.color.warning}}','{{app.color.danger}}'],
                grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true, borderWidth: 0, color: '#333333' },
                tooltip: true,
                tooltipOpts: { content: '%s: %p.0%',  defaultTheme: false, shifts: { x: 0, y: 20 } }
              }
            " style="height:240px"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

chartdata has json data set to drow pie chart.

**Problem**

if i have set dynamically value  of $scope.chartdata on $http request then not binding data on chart.also not working on timeout.so how to reload ui-option and bind data on chart.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution by this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929618/ui-jq-flot-chart-on-lazy-load)

Use:   `ui-refresh="chartdata"` before ui-option on chart